# Graph, fill in boxes and put labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I need to make the following graph.[image]

And I carry the following, with the following code,

```
\begin{center}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9]

\draw[<->] (-1,0) -- (2*pi,0) node[below] {$x$};

\draw[thick] (4,0)--(4,1/2);

\draw[thick] (4,0)--(4,-1/2);

\draw[thick] (1.3,1/2)--(1.3,-1/2);

\draw[thick] (2.6,1/2)--(2.6,-1/2);

\draw (0,-1/6) node[left] {};

\draw[<->] (0,-1) -- (0, 3) node[left] {$y$};

\draw[-,domain = 0:4,thick]

 plot (\x,{1/2}) node[right] {};

\draw[-,domain = 0:4,thick]

 plot (\x,{-1/2}) node[right] {};

 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
```

[image]

I would need to fill in the table and put the labels. Someone could help me on that, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the labels with `\node`s the same way as you did in the axes. For the filling the Ti*k*Z library `patterns` could be helpful. And finally, you can draw the brace with the library `decorations.pathreplacing`.

I changed your original scale, otherwise the text will be very big, in my opinion. You can revert that or change the text size if you want.

The code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing} % for the overbrace

\tikzset%
{% this sytle provides the overbrace (form decorations.pathreplacing)
  mybrace/.style={decorate,decoration={brace,raise=2mm,amplitude=3pt}},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,line join=round,line cap=round]
% axes
\draw[<->] (-1,0) -- (2*pi,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[<->] (0,-1) -- (0, 3)   node[left]  {$y$};
% big rectangle (and nodes, labels)
\draw[thick] (0,-1/2) node [below left] {\strut$x=0$} -- (4,-1/2) node [below] {\strut$x=\ell$} |- (0,1/2);
% filled rectangle (and another node)
\draw[thick,pattern=north east lines] (1.3,-1/2) node [below] {\strut$x$} rectangle (2.6,1/2);
% one more node
\node at (2.6,-1/2) [below] {$x+\Delta x$};
% overbrace
\draw[mybrace]   (1.3,1/2) -- (2.6,1/2) node[midway,yshift=5mm] {\strut $\Delta x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Where do I see that of libraries? There is a page that tells you something about that, to learn more about the tool. Again thank you very much :).

Comment: @JamesA.Agamez. You can consult the Ti*k*Z/PGF manual at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf, or with `texdoc tikz`.